# Is it possible write test of all hex opcodes which gathers the statistics to find undocumented features?

Tags: assembly

Statistics of all the possible changes (ports flags regs interrupts exceptions.. etc) and writing it into the array (to view and compare). It counts the length of opcode ...etc .

It might be that such a standard test exists, for example to test any given processor. And there is no special need of "magical uncoverings" of undocumented features, that you could fount across the net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention the processor type you would target. This answer is from x86 perspective, but probably the task would be similar in other architectures too.

First, what would limit you to write and run such a program? If you have root access (possibility to run ring0 code in x86 terminology) on the computer, you could do the following:

1. hook all necessary interrupts (or maybe you can hook **all** the interrupts).
2. generate an instruction.
3. write the instruction code to memory (there may be different instruction lengths).
4. write a `jmp`, `call`, `int` or `int3` after the instruction (in x86 processors, in other architectures the instructions would be different).
5. jump to the instruction, it gets executed or causes an interrupt. If it gets executed, after it you'll jump or call the handling code. If it causes an interrupt, check `cs:ip` from the stack (to know at what address the instruction failed), which interrupt you are in etc., and then jump or call the handling code.

Then, in the handling code, send all the data you want (all the registers at the least, I suppose) to some external port, and then on another computer store all the data on disk.

1. Then generate the next instruction.
2. Jump to 3 unless you have already handled all the instructions.

However, in the case of x86 the maximum allowed instruction length is 15 bytes. 256^15 = 1.33 * 10^36. The age of the universe is ~4.339 * 10^17 seconds. Assuming a 10.0 GHz processor with a single core, exactly 1 instruction per clock (to try and report it), you would need more than 300 000 000 such processors to get all 15-byte instructions tested in less time than the current age of the universe:

```
(256^15)/(10*10^9)/(4.339*10^17) = 306344317
```

Of course you would need quite a lot of storage space too.